# PrimeFaces password toggleMask: two togglers for Edge browser

Tags: primefaces, passwords, toggle, microsoft-edge

PrimeFaces password toggleMask: two togglers for Edge browser.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

Reproducer:

1. clear the password for toggle mask.
2. enter any password, an additional toggler will show.

Version: 12.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue opened: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9880

Fixed in 13.0.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/9881

If you need the fix right now just add this CSS to your page:

```css
.ui-password > input::-ms-reveal,
.ui-password > input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: actually I just updated my answer to be correct. I tried a few things yesterday and my CSS must have been cached the right answer is now above

Answer (score 0):

Just as additional information to @Melloware 's answer, you can simply apply:

```
::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

to remove the Edge password reveal button.

Comment: This is already in the answer.

Comment: @JasperdeVries, exactly, but I tried Melloware's idea and found it did not work (it should but I have no idea why it didn't). Then I tried a basic "hiding reveal button" script like this, and it worked.

Comment: I corrected my answer below.